# Why is the lifetime of `&_x` is shorter than that of `y` in this example?

Tags: rust

I am working my way through Rust by Example book and I am confused [by an example provided in the chapter on Lifetimes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/scope/lifetime/explicit.html).

```rust
// `print_refs` takes two references to `i32` which have different
// lifetimes `'a` and `'b`. These two lifetimes must both be at
// least as long as the function `print_refs`.
fn print_refs<'a, 'b>(x: &'a i32, y: &'b i32) {
    println!("x is {} and y is {}", x, y);
}

// A function which takes no arguments, but has a lifetime parameter `'a`.
fn failed_borrow<'a>() {
    let _x = 12;

    // ERROR: `_x` does not live long enough
    let y: &'a i32 = &_x; // <- this will error out
    // Attempting to use the lifetime `'a` as an explicit type annotation 
    // inside the function will fail because the lifetime of `&_x` is shorter
    // than that of `y`. A short lifetime cannot 
    // be coerced into a longer one.
}

fn main() {
    // Create variables to be borrowed below.
    let (four, nine) = (4, 9);
    
    // Borrows (`&`) of both variables are passed into the function.
    print_refs(&four, &nine);
    // Any input which is borrowed must outlive the borrower. 
    // In other words, the lifetime of `four` and `nine` must 
    // be longer than that of `print_refs`.
    
    failed_borrow();
    // `failed_borrow` contains no references to force `'a` to be 
    // longer than the lifetime of the function, but `'a` is longer.
    // Because the lifetime is never constrained, it defaults to `'static`.
}
```

I don't understand why it states that "the lifetime of `&_x` is shorter than that of `y`" inside the function `failed_borrow<'a>()`. Surely the lifetime of &_x is the same as y as they are both declared inside the function. What am I missing?

Comment: A function without arguments is not a good example of lifetimes. A lifetime describes the scope of a value on a _caller's_ stack. One "creates" a lifetime by declaring a variable, taking its reference, and sending that reference to a function that names its lifetime. The lifetime can then be passed to other functions down the call chain. Lifetime being "chosen by the caller" means that the caller chooses how long the value lives _compared to other values_. Named lifetimes like `'a` and `'b` allow a function's signature to specify what kind of data it is returning compared to what it received.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that your function is generic over a lifetime, so it must work for *any* lifetime. Imagine, for instance, that it was instantiated with the `'static` lifetime. It means that `y: &'static i32 = &x`, but clearly `x` does not live long enough to provide a `'static` borrow, because `x` is bound to the function, so it will be dropped at the end of it.

This is not related to how much time `y` lives, but for how much time the borrow to `x` is required to live. Indeed, if you remove the generic lifetime, Rust will now pick a sensible lifetime for the borrow, and it will compile.

Comment: I wouldn't call this "monomorphized" as codegen doesn't create a unique instance for each lifetime. "Instantiated" is perhaps a better term.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I had a doubt about it when writing, thanks for the confirmation. Edited.